# MariaDB - Invoice Numbers - Return to 0 each year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Hello,

I would like advice please because I develop a CRM that generates quotes and invoices (in PHP / MariaDB).

What is the best way to generate the invoice numbers (so that there is never a conflict in the database - never duplicate for a number, etc.) ?

*PS :
I want every beginning of the year (01 January) to start again the invoice numbers to zero.
And the CRM will be used by several stores, I want a separate numbering for each store.*

At first, I thought I'd put an **number** column (int) in my order table (**order_invoices**). And in PHP when creating a new invoice do like this (example with Eloquent de Laravel):

```
$lastNumber = OrderInvoice::whereRaw(
        'number = (
            SELECT MAX(number) FROM order_invoices
        )'
    )
    ->first()
    ->number;

$orderInvoice = new OrderInvoice();
$orderInvoice->number = $lastNumber + 1;
// other... assigne values to others columns
$orderInvoice->save();
```

But after reflection, I'm not sure that this is the best solution (I use transactions so high traffic on the CRM and several members validate a command at the same time ... risk of conflict in the incrementation of billing numbers ?).

A developer I know, had advised me for example to create a **counters** table. And in this table:

_Add as columns: **id**, **number** (this column will be incremented to know where we are in the numbering).

_In this table, put a line (row) for each store.

_And in my program (action of my controller), for the creation of a new invoice:

_To make a lock on a row (on the store line) at the beginning of the generation of the invoice;

_To retrieve **number** from the **counters** table, and this value to insert it (with a +1) into **number** of the invoice table (**order_invoices**);

What do you think ? And do you have any other ideas and advice please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Add a `year` column, then `SELECT MAX(number) FROM order_invoices WHERE year=?` and you can lock it down to a particular year. Barring that, if you have a "created" column: `SELECT MAX(number) FROM order_invoices WHERE YEAR(created_at)=?` though this is a lot slower since it can't be indexed. Remember this code will suffer from race conditions. Be prepared to retry an `INSERT` on a conflicting entry. You'll want a `UNIQUE` index on `number,year`.

Comment: Implementation aside, resetting invoices numbers every year is going to drive your accountant, and any accountants of your clients, *completely up the wall*. Invoice numbers should start at 1 and increment from there, never resetting, never repeating. There's nothing worse than trying to figure out if invoice 521 is paid when there's potentially several with identical numbers for the same customer.

Comment: Why don't you use one schema for the invoice number ? Like YYYYSTORE_ID-AUTOINCREMENT ? Should be 201900100001 and the only thing you have to get is the last part of the number and add 1 to it

Comment: That's not really a 'ps', is it? It seems like the main point!

Comment: Selecting `MAX` and then adding one is subject to race conditions. Two invoices created at exactly the same time could get the same invoice number, or if its unique, one will fail to create. Perhaps [MariaDB-10.3 sequences could help](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-overview/)

Comment: About clients with strange and harmful requirements on inconsequential items like invoice numbers, recommend finding another one. They aren't focusing on their business or the value of the services being tasked, they may not exist for long and you probably don't want to work for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [MariaDB-10.3 Sequence](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-overview/).

Retrieving the [next invoice number](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/next-value-for-sequence_name/):

```
NEXT VALUE FOR invoice_number
```

Create a yearly event:

```
CREATE EVENT reset_invoice_number
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR
DO 
ALTER SEQUENCE invoice_number RESTART 0
```

Comment: Thank you everyone

Comment: PS. Still a crazy requirement

Answer (score 2):

A schema only:

database members:

- main_id auto increment primary key
- year
- index_of_year
- unique key(year,index_of_year)

Progress:

- Insert element with year, set index_of_year to NULL
- Get last inserted id as CUR_ID
- Update index_of_year of the record to max+1